# nsmutablearray float object returns a zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In the root model I have:

```
[self.rPrices replaceObjectAtIndex:0
                        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)nR4]]; 
NSLog(@"%.2f", [self.rPrices objectAtIndex:0]);
```

where rPrices is `NSMutableArray`.

nR4 is not zero but the above `NSLog(...);` displays zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", [[self.rPrices objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
```

or alternativly just print the `NSNumber` as an object

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.rPrices objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

NSNumber is an object. So you can't print it using float format specifier "%f".

You can use "%@" or get the float value from it using `-floatValue` and print it using "%f".